# visual studio dll as a dependent project

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, dependencies

I have a project and added a dll project as a second project in the solution and made the build order be correct.  I need to tell my exe where to find the dll.  I know I can add the dll as a reference in the exe but that does not let me switch between the debug dll and release with out having to reset the path when i switch between the 2.  How can I tell the exe that I want it to use this dll and use the debug one in debug mode and release one in release mode.

Comment: What is a dll project? What happens when you build the main project in release mode and try to run it?

Comment: a project that creates a dll, it runs fine but I don't want to have a release exe with a debug dll.

Comment: If you a adding reference as a project reference then you don't need to worry about debug or release build. Visual studio will build both the projects with the same build configuration and the main project will have the dll of other project in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Use project references instead. Right click your references node and select `Add Reference` , then in the dialog, you can select projects that exist in your solution:

[image]

Using project references ensures that your configuration works with both debug and release builds.